# Function that queries DB with Knex.js returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node.js server which I'll use to handle a website. I'm trying to make an API to interact with the database. I have to use Knex.js to manage the database.

The initialization of Knex and the creation of the database and its single table (at the moment) goes fine. What I'm trying to do here is a function that, given an id as argument, will lookup the corresponding row and return it.

Here I create the table:

```
// create tables in the database
function createDoctorsTable() {
    jcdb.schema.hasTable("doctors").then(function (exists) {
        if (!exists) {
            jcdb.schema.createTable("doctors", function (table) {
                table.integer("id");
                table.string("name").notNullable();
                table.string("surname").notNullable();
                table.string("presentation");
                table.string("professional_story");
                table.string("photo");
                table.string("mail");
                table.string("phone");
            }).then(function () {
                return Promise.all(
                    _.map(doctorsDBfile, function (v) {
                        return jcdb("doctors").insert(v);
                    })
                );
            });
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the function I'm trying to do.

```
function getDoctorById(id) {
    var result;
    jcdb("doctors").where("id", id)
        .then(function(query) {
        result = JSON.stringify(query);
        });
    return result;
}
```

Then I call everything I need:

```
app.set("port", serverPort);

init_jcdb();
createDoctorsTable();

/* Start the server on port 3000 */
app.listen(serverPort, function() {
  console.log(`Your app is ready at port ${serverPort}`);
  console.log(getDoctorById(2));
});
```

The call to getDoctorById() returns undefined! While if i put the console.log() inside the function, it correctly prints the row.
What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm a total noob in js, just yesterday I've seen it for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getDoctorById(id) {
    var result;
    jcdb("doctors").where("id", id)
        .then(function(query) {
        result = JSON.stringify(query);
        });
    return result;
}
```

try instead:

```
function getDoctorById(id) {
    return jcdb("doctors").where("id", id)
        .then(function(query) {
            var result = JSON.stringify(query);
            return result;
        });
}
```

Promises let you use Asynchronous code more easily.
When using `then`, you're actually calling a callback function, with the result(s) of the previous promise in the chain as the parameter(s) of the callback function.

But in order to do so, you have to return a value from within the promise's callback (the function you pass to `then`), which is the value that is going to go in the callback's parameters,

and also return the promise-returning-function itself (in this case, `jcdb`) - because, remember, only promises have a `then`.

Following the same logic,
you cannot `console.log()` the function like you do here:

```
console.log(getDoctorById(2));
```

Because, remember, the function returns a `promise`, not a value. it indirectly returns the value/s as its callback function's parameters. which gives us:

```
getDoctorById(2).then(function(result) {
    console.log("result:", result);
})
```

One last thing,
your first function, `createDoctorsTable()`, is also asynchronous; it might, in some cases, execute before `getDoctorById()`.

So first, let's return a promise from your `createDoctorsTable()`, so that we can make `getDoctorById` strictly run after it:

```
function createDoctorsTable() {
    return jcdb.schema.hasTable("doctors").then(function (exists) {
    .......
```

(Notice: I only added the return statement, the rest looks good).

and then change your `app.listen`, to make your final code look something like this (assuming `init_jcdb()` returns a promise):

```
// create tables in the database
function createDoctorsTable() {
    return jcdb.schema.hasTable("doctors").then(function (exists) {
        if (!exists) {
            jcdb.schema.createTable("doctors", function (table) {
                table.integer("id");
                table.string("name").notNullable();
                table.string("surname").notNullable();
                table.string("presentation");
                table.string("professional_story");
                table.string("photo");
                table.string("mail");
                table.string("phone");
            }).then(function () {
                return Promise.all(
                    _.map(doctorsDBfile, function (v) {
                        return jcdb("doctors").insert(v);
                    })
                );
            });
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

function getDoctorById(id) {
    return jcdb("doctors").where("id", id)
        .then(function(query) {
            var result = JSON.stringify(query);
            return result;
        });
}


app.set("port", serverPort);

    init_jcdb()
        .then(function() {
            return createDoctorsTable();
        })
        .then(function() {
            getDoctorById(2).then(function(result) {
                console.log("result:", result);
            })
        })
        .then(function() {
            /* Start the server on port 3000 */
            app.listen(serverPort, function() {
                console.log(`Your app is ready at port ${serverPort}`);
            }
        });
});
```

There are plenty of variations for writing this code.

I suggest you read more about JavaScript's asynchronous model, and promises in javascript.

Comment: Can't I make the function directly return the value? How would I use this function, for example, in an http page where I need the value in the database for a specific id? I thought that returning a value would be simple to manage.
And for createDoctorsTable(), I thought about the asynchrony and  tried to make them as subsequent calls, but I didn't have much success ahah
Anyway thank you so much :)

Comment: You can't do that :) this is due to JavaScript's asynchronous nature; JS uses only 1 thread to run it's synchronous code, such as function calls.

Asynchronous code, such as the code behind your jcdb function, uses binding to the JS engine implementation, which runs them in parallel to the main thread, but in a transparent manner - you can't access the other threads and you can pretend they don't exist.

This is why code doesn't always run in the same order you've written it.